# Closed and Bounded set

Tags: general-topology

We were thrown a bit of a curveball question in our first topology class, and I'm a bit puzzled by it.

The question is, is the set ${x=1}$ closed and bounded? The set is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I started with thinking that $x=1$ is a set that contains its own boundary, but don't know where else to go from here!

Thanks.
Thomas

Comment: The set $x=1$ sitting in what space? $[0,1]$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R^2$, ... ? What's the topological space?

Comment: Ahh yes, good point. I have edited the question, it is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: The question is unclear. What is meant by ‘the set $x=1$’? Since you say that this is taking place in $\Bbb R^n$, do you mean $$\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_1=1\}\;,$$ the set of points with first coordinate $1$? If $n=2$, this is the line $x=1$ parallel to the $y$ axis; if $n=3$, it’s the plane $x=1$ parallel to the $yz$-plane.

Comment: What do you mean by $x=1$ in $\Bbb R^n$? Is it $\{1\} \subset \Bbb R$, or is it $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Bbb R^n \mid x_1 = 1\}$?

Comment: I agree, the notation $x=1$ is very much unclear; as written, it does not define a subset of $R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Rely on the definition...

$S=\{1\}$ is obviously bounded

Any converging sequence of $S$ does converge in $S$ (it is constant of value $1$)

In case your question concerns a hyperplane of a multi-dimentional space :

- It is not bounded (I think you can come up with a divergent sequence in this hyperplane)
- Any converging sequence of this hyperplane does converge in it

Comment: Yes, but is it closed?

Comment: Vincent answered that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks Vincent. The topology is actually that of $R^n$.